# Why does Number.MIN_VALUE < -1219312 (or any small value) evaluate to false?

Tags: javascript

I've tried this in multiple browsers and they all evaluate to false! Am I missing something here?

Comment: because it's positive?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE

Comment: I can understand that this may be surprising, given that `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` returns a negative number (anything else wouldn't make sense), but documentation is readily available.

Comment: Upvote, pretty good question, worth showing up in search results, despite the "d'oh!" effect.

Answer (score 4):

Because `Number.MIN_VALUE` is the smallest *positive* value.

(Not sure what people like to link to for reference; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE for instance).

Comment: That seems counter-intuitive... Most other languages have MIN_VALUE as the most negative.

Answer (score 3):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE):

> The `Number.MIN_VALUE` property represents the smallest **positive** numeric value representable in JavaScript.
>
> The MIN_VALUE property is the number closest to 0, not the most negative number, that JavaScript can represent.

`Number.MIN_VALUE` is a really small decimal value, not a really negative value.

Comment: Ah, I see. How can I get the smallest and largest `Number`?

Comment: @SubparWebDev You can use `Number.MAX_VALUE` and `-Number.MAX_VALUE`. Anything higher or lower will be +/-Infinity.